# 3d carousel slider with 8 slides using html and css (js would be also ok)

Tags: slider, carousel

I have found this slider from codepen.io, which I rally like to implement in my website, but I need it with 8 slides.

I thought that I ust have to add the other slides in my html and also in css, but after doing this the pagination is not working correctly. It starts with the last slide and some slides are not shown. I dont know why, hopefully some of us can help, why the slider with 8 slides are not working and why the slider with 5 slides is working.

Here is the Code and the link from codepen.io

```
`codepen.io/RajTemplate/pen/rNwJmGM`
```

```
/**CSS **/


#slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 32vw;
  margin: 150px auto;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  perspective: 1400px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

input[type=radio] {
  position: relative;
  top: 108%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: translateX(-83px);
  cursor: pointer;
}


input[type=radio]:nth-child(5) {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked {
  opacity: 1;
}




#slider label,
#slider label img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: transform 400ms ease;
}



/* Slider Functionality */

/* Active Slide */
#s1:checked ~ #slide1,
 #s2:checked ~ #slide2,
  #s3:checked ~ #slide3,
   #s4:checked ~ #slide4,
    #s5:checked ~ #slide5 {
  box-shadow: 0 13px 26px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3), 0 12px 6px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
  transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0px);
}

/* Next Slide */
#s1:checked ~ #slide2,
 #s2:checked ~ #slide3,
  #s3:checked ~ #slide4,
   #s4:checked ~ #slide5,
    #s5:checked ~ #slide1 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
  transform: translate3d(20%, 0, -100px);
}


/* Next to Next Slide */
#s1:checked ~ #slide3,
 #s2:checked ~ #slide4,
  #s3:checked ~ #slide5,
   #s4:checked ~ #slide1,
    #s5:checked ~ #slide2 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
  transform: translate3d(40%, 0, -250px);
}

/* Previous to Previous Slide */
#s1:checked ~ #slide4,
 #s2:checked ~ #slide5,
  #s3:checked ~ #slide1,
   #s4:checked ~ #slide2,
    #s5:checked ~ #slide3 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
  transform: translate3d(-40%, 0, -250px);
}

/* Previous Slide */
#s1:checked ~ #slide5,
 #s2:checked ~ #slide1,
  #s3:checked ~ #slide2,
   #s4:checked ~ #slide3,
    #s5:checked ~ #slide4 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
  transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, -100px);
}

/*** HTML ***/

<section id="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s3">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s4">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s5">

  <label for="s1" id="slide1"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2b/de/de/2bdede0647e3cdf75b44ea33723201d9.jpg" alt=""></label>
  <label for="s2" id="slide2"><img src="https://images6.alphacoders.com/462/thumb-1920-462371.jpg" alt=""></label>
  <label for="s3" id="slide3"><img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1154341.jpg" alt=""></label>
  <label for="s4" id="slide4"><img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2634222.jpg" alt=""></label>
  <label for="s5" id="slide5"><img src="https://images5.alphacoders.com/343/thumb-1920-343645.jpg" alt=""></label>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my code, I tried:

```
/*** HTML ***/

<section id="slider"><input id="s1" checked="checked" name="slider" type="radio" /> <input id="s2" name="slider" type="radio" /> <input id="s3" name="slider" type="radio" /> <input id="s4" name="slider" type="radio" /> <input id="s5" name="slider" type="radio" /> <input id="s6" name="slider" type="radio" /> <input id="s7" name="slider" type="radio" />  <input id="s8" name="slider" type="radio" />

  
  
  
<label id="slide1" for="s1"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="">Test1</label>
  
  <label id="slide2" for="s2"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="">Test2</label>

<label id="slide3" for="s3"><img src="image3.jpg" alt="">Test3</label>

<label id="slide4" for="s4"><img src="image4.jpg" alt="">Test4</label>

<label id="slide5" for="s5"><img src="image5.jpg" alt="">Test5</label>

<label id="slide6" for="s6"><img src="image6.jpg" alt="">Test6</label>

<label id="slide7" for="s7"><img src="image7.jpg" alt="">Test7</label>

<label id="slide8" for="s8"><img src="image8.jpg" alt="">Test8</label>


</section>
```

```
/*** CSS ***/

#slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 32vw;
  margin: 150px auto;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  perspective: 1400px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

input[type=radio] {
  position: relative;
  top: 108%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: translateX(-83px);
  cursor: pointer;
}


input[type=radio]:nth-child(8) {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked {
  opacity: 1;
}




#slider label,
#slider label img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: transform 400ms ease;
}

.arrows{
   width: 48px;
   height: 48px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -31px;
}

.prev{
   left: 10px;
   z-index: 200;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover{
  color: var(--logo_color);
}
   
.next{
   right: 10px;
   z-index: 200;
}

.arrows::before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 free';
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.prev::before {
  content: '\f0a8'; /* Unicode for the Font Awesome chevron-left icon */
}

.next::before {
  content: '\f0a9';
}



/* Slider Functionality */


/* Next Slide on Next Arrow Click */
.next:hover ~ input:checked ~ input ~ input ~ input ~ #slide1,
.next:hover ~ input:checked ~ input ~ input ~ input ~ #slide2,
.next:hover ~ input:checked ~ input ~ input ~ input ~ #slide3,
.next:hover ~ input:checked ~ input ~ input ~ input ~ #slide4,
.next:hover ~ input:checked ~ input ~ input ~ input ~ #slide5,
.next:hover ~ input:checked ~ input ~ input ~ input ~ #slide6,
.next:hover ~ input:checked ~ input ~ input ~ input ~ #slide7,
.next:hover ~ input:checked ~ input ~ input ~ input ~ #slide8  {
    box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    transform: translate3d(20%, 0, -100px);
}

/* Previous Slide on Previous Arrow Click */
.prev:hover ~ input:checked ~ #slide8,
.prev:hover ~ input:checked ~ #slide1,
.prev:hover ~ input:checked ~ #slide2,
.prev:hover ~ input:checked ~ #slide3,
.prev:hover ~ input:checked ~ #slide4,
.prev:hover ~ input:checked ~ #slide5,
.prev:hover ~ input:checked ~ #slide6,
.prev:hover ~ input:checked ~ #slide7 {
    box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, -100px);
}



/* Active Slide */
#s1:checked ~ #slide1,
 #s2:checked ~ #slide2,
  #s3:checked ~ #slide3,
   #s4:checked ~ #slide4,
    #s5:checked ~ #slide5,
    #s6:checked ~ #slide6,
    #s7:checked ~ #slide7,
    #s8:checked ~ #slide8 {
  box-shadow: 0 13px 26px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3), 0 12px 6px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
  transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0px);
}

/* Next Slide */
#s1:checked ~ #slide2,
 #s2:checked ~ #slide3,
  #s3:checked ~ #slide4,
   #s4:checked ~ #slide5,
    #s5:checked ~ #slide6,
    #s6:checked ~ #slide7,
    #s7:checked ~ #slide8,
    #s8:checked ~ #slide1 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
  transform: translate3d(20%, 0, -100px);
}


/* Next to Next Slide */
#s1:checked ~ #slide3,
 #s2:checked ~ #slide4,
  #s3:checked ~ #slide5,
   #s4:checked ~ #slide6,
    #s5:checked ~ #slide7,
    #s6:checked ~ #slide8,
    #s7:checked ~ #slide1,
    #s8:checked ~ #slide2 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
  transform: translate3d(40%, 0, -250px);
}

/* Previous to Previous Slide */
#s1:checked ~ #slide4,
 #s2:checked ~ #slide5,
  #s3:checked ~ #slide6,
   #s4:checked ~ #slide7,
    #s5:checked ~ #slide8,
    #s6:checked ~ #slide1,
    #s7:checked ~ #slide2,
    #s8:checked ~ #slide3 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
  transform: translate3d(-40%, 0, -250px);
}

/* Previous Slide */
#s1:checked ~ #slide5,
 #s2:checked ~ #slide6,
  #s3:checked ~ #slide7,
   #s4:checked ~ #slide8,
    #s5:checked ~ #slide1,
    #s6:checked ~ #slide2,
    #s7:checked ~ #slide3,
    #s8:checked ~ #slide4 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
  transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, -100px);
}

 

    a .label_titel{
      color: black;
      font-size:  50px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Where is my error?

Thanks in advance, Newbie

Comment: `input[type=radio]:nth-child(5)` sure looks specific to 5 slides; so does having 5 blocks under `/* Slider Functionality */`.

Comment: sorry, you are right, I also changed that to 8, but without any changes

Answer (score 0):

```css
body > div {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    figure {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .container {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 60px auto;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
        -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% -25%;
    }

        .carousel {
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(-540px);
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
            width: 500px;
            height: 200px;
            -webkit-transition: 1s;
        }

            .carousel img {
                position: absolute;
                border: 6px solid rgb(12 47 17 / 80%);
                opacity: .5;
                -webkit-transition: 1s;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        background:#ccc;
            }

                
                .carousel img:nth-child(1) { -webkit-transform: translateZ(540px) scale(.8); }
                .carousel img:nth-child(2) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(540px) scale(.8); }
                .carousel img:nth-child(3) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(540px) scale(.8); }
                .carousel img:nth-child(4) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(540px) scale(.8); }
                .carousel img:nth-child(5) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(540px) scale(.8); }
                .carousel img:nth-child(6) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(540px) scale(.8); }
                .carousel img:nth-child(7) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(540px) scale(.8); }
                .carousel img:nth-child(8) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(540px) scale(.8); }

    label {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #eee;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 30px;
        padding-top: 7px;
        height: 23px;
        font: .9em Arial;
    }

    label:hover {
        background: #ddd;
    }

    input {
        position: absolute;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    input:checked + label {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #323232;
    color: #fff;
}

        input[value="1"]:checked ~ .container .carousel { -webkit-transform: translateZ(-540px); }
        input[value="2"]:checked ~ .container .carousel { -webkit-transform: translateZ(-540px) rotateY(-45deg); }
        input[value="3"]:checked ~ .container .carousel { -webkit-transform: translateZ(-540px) rotateY(-90deg); }
        input[value="4"]:checked ~ .container .carousel { -webkit-transform: translateZ(-540px) rotateY(-135deg); }
        input[value="5"]:checked ~ .container .carousel { -webkit-transform: translateZ(-540px) rotateY(-180deg); }
        input[value="6"]:checked ~ .container .carousel { -webkit-transform: translateZ(-540px) rotateY(-225deg); }
        input[value="7"]:checked ~ .container .carousel { -webkit-transform: translateZ(-540px) rotateY(-270deg); }
        input[value="8"]:checked ~ .container .carousel { -webkit-transform: translateZ(-540px) rotateY(-315deg); }

        input[value="1"]:checked ~ .container .carousel img:nth-child(1) { -webkit-transform: translateZ(540px) scale(1); opacity: 1; }
        input[value="2"]:checked ~ .container .carousel img:nth-child(2) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(540px) scale(1); opacity: 1; }
        input[value="3"]:checked ~ .container .carousel img:nth-child(3) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(540px) scale(1); opacity: 1; }
        input[value="4"]:checked ~ .container .carousel img:nth-child(4) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(540px) scale(1); opacity: 1; }
        input[value="5"]:checked ~ .container .carousel img:nth-child(5) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(540px) scale(1); opacity: 1; }
        input[value="6"]:checked ~ .container .carousel img:nth-child(6) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(540px) scale(1); opacity: 1; }
        input[value="7"]:checked ~ .container .carousel img:nth-child(7) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(540px) scale(1); opacity: 1; }
        input[value="8"]:checked ~ .container .carousel img:nth-child(8) { -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(540px) scale(1); opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<body>

    <div>

        <input checked id="one" name="multiples" type="radio" value="1">
        <label for="one">1</label>

        <input id="two" name="multiples" type="radio" value="2">
        <label for="two">2</label>

        <input id="three" name="multiples" type="radio" value="3">
        <label for="three">3</label>

        <input id="four" name="multiples" type="radio" value="4">
        <label for="four">4</label>

        <input id="five" name="multiples" type="radio" value="5">
        <label for="five">5</label>

        <input id="six" name="multiples" type="radio" value="6">
        <label for="six">6</label>

        <input id="seven" name="multiples" type="radio" value="7">
        <label for="seven">7</label>

        <input id="eight" name="multiples" type="radio" value="8">
        <label for="eight">8</label>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel">
                <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Slide 1">
                <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Slide 2">
                <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="Slide 3">
                <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="Slide 4">
                <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="Slide 5">
                <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="Slide 6">
                <img src="images/7.jpg" alt="Slide 7">
                <img src="images/8.jpg" alt="Slide 8">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```